# XmlDocument opening from URL

Tags: c#, xml

I am using XmlDocument to open a remote XML document

```
string apiURL = Settings.Settings.URLBaseAPI + "user.php";

apiURL = apiURL + "?u=" + Settings.Settings.ForumUsername
       + "&p=" + MD5Tool.GetMD5Hash(Settings.Settings.ForumPassword)
       + "&mode=token";

doc.Load(apiURL);
```

Is there anyway to set the user agent for the internet access performed to retrieve the XML document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When loading through the `doc.Load(string)` method, this is not possible.

You can try and retrieve the xml with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), which will allow overriding some HTTP headers then use `doc.LoadXML(string)` to populate your XmlDocument.

Comment: Sounds like that should work - I'll give it a go. Probably should have been using WebClient all along in any case.

Comment: If you are retrieving documents via http, using WebClient or one of the other System.Net classes gives you much more control over the connection.